# CouchDB with continuous replication reverts document revision instead of deleting

Tags: couchdb, replication

We have a system that uses CouchDB as its database.
We are using continuous replication to create an always-updated copy of our database.

Recently we have discovered a strange behavior (maybe bug?) that I hope someone here could help me with:

We set the system with normal replication (**NOT** filtered).

We update the same document several times consecutively (each time waiting for CouchDB to return 200ok) - this part works fine and the document appears to be updated just fine in the replicated DB.

However, when we try to delete this document, even minutes after the consecutive updates, it is not deleted in the replication DB and instead just reverts to a revision before the consecutive updates.

It is important to note that we delete by adding a **_deleted** field set to **true**

I understand there is some problem with deletion using HTTP DELETE combined with filtered replication, but we're not using either.
Also, doing the same updates and just waiting a second between one and the other solves the problem just fine (or just combining them to one update).
However both solutions are not possible and at any case just go around the problem.

## tl;dr:

1) CouchDB with normal continuous replication

2) Consecutive updates to document

3) _deleted = trueto document

4) Replicated DB does not delete, instead reverts to _rev before #2

## Environment:

CouchDB version is 1.6.1

Windows computer

Using CouchDB-Lucene

Comment: Just to be sure, whenever you put _deleted to true on a document, the property is not replicated to your replicate DB ?

Comment: that's half true. It's not that the document in the replicate DB is not effected at all. It reverts back to an earlier version.

When I checked it with ?all_rev=true I can see that the newer revisions do get _deleted=true property, but the revision from before the consecutive updates does not. Which is why, I guess, it becomes the revision the replicate CouchDB returns when asked for the doc.

The main CouchDB, however, add _deleted=true to all its revisions.

Comment: just a correction. When I wrote "?all_rev=true" I meant "open_revs=all"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
It was the revision limit.
Seems that quickly doing changes that are over the revision limit causes problem for the replication mechanism.

There is an unsolved bug in CouchDB about this issue:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1649

Since the revision limit we had was 2, doing 3 consecutive updates to the same document and then deleting it caused this problem.
Setting the revision limit to 5 avoids it.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have introduced some conflicts in the documents. When a document is being edited in several replicas, CouchDB chooses a winning revision when replicating, but also keeps the losing revisions. If you delete the winning revision, the losing revision will be displayed again. You can read an introduction in the (now somewhat outdated) CouchDB Guide: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/conflicts.html and in the CouchDB Docs: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/replication/conflicts.html

But in short, the replication database might have been edited by someone. It might be that you replicated several databases into one, or somebody edited the documents manually in the target database.

You can delete the target database and recreate an empty db. If you don't edit the target db by hand and don't replicate multiple dbs into one, _deletes will be replicated correctly from then.